# Need the save button in New/Edit Form to save the form but not close it upon clicking

Tags: list-form

I want the New/Edit list form to remain open for editing when save is clicked. However it should save the changes. The form should finally close when x or cancel is clicked. Is their a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily in InfoPath. Just edit the current list forms, and add 2 buttons called saving and cancel. Add a rule for the save button to submit data, and a rule for the cancel button to close the form. Publish the form.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the below link:

[Javascript Code URL](http://spjsblog.com/2011/04/23/redirect-from-newform-to-dispform-or-editform/)

Steps to follow:

1) Adding script code in a CEWP for NewForm.aspx:

2) In EditForm.aspx, add script code in a CEWP

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Include the important part of the link in your post. If the link breaks your answers will be of no help to future readers

Comment: actually the script is too big and it would a big answer again, so i am posting a link here.i hope its ok.

Comment: It must be possible to at least type some of the major steps to take to your post? Anything that makes your answer less dependent on the link would be a very good edit :)

Comment: sure will edit with some explanation. no problem. thanks!